# Linux: GNU sort does not sort seq

Tags: bash, sorting, gnu-sort

Title sums it up.

```
$ echo `seq 0 10` `seq 5 15` | sort -n
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Why doesn't this work?

Even if I don't use `seq`:

```
echo '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15' | sort -n
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

And even ditching `echo` directly:

```
$ echo '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15' > numbers
$ sort -n numbers 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sort(1)` sorts *lines*. You have to parse whitespace delimited data yourself:

```
echo `seq 0 10` `seq 5 15` | tr " " "\n" | sort -n
```

Comment: Note that I can't test this with `seq(1)` (not installed on OS X), but this works for `echo(1)` for me just fine.

Answer (score 9):

Because you need newlines for `sort`:

```
$ echo `seq 0 10` `seq 5 15` | tr " " "\\n" | sort -n | tr "\\n" " "; echo ""
0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 12 13 14 15
$
```

Answer (score 5):

You have single line of input. There is nothing to sort.

Comment: Well, technically, there *is* something to sort, but it's simple and blindingly fast :-)

Answer (score 3):

The command as you typed it results in the sequence of numbers being all passed to `sort` in one line. That's not what you want. Just pass the output of `seq` directly to `sort`:

```
(seq 0 10; seq 5 15) | sort -n
```

By the way, as you just found out, the construct

```
echo `command`
```

doesn't *usually* do what you expect and is redundant for what you actually expect: It tells the shell to capture the output of `command` and pass it to `echo`, which produces it as output again. Just let the output of the command go through directly (unless you **really** mean to have it processed by `echo`, maybe to expand escape sequences, or to collapse everything to one line).

Comment: 'doesn't do what you expect' - Actually it did *exactly* what I expected it to do. I just didn't remember `sort` to sort lines :D

Comment: I was referring to the general use of the construct. You usually don't expect to collapse all text into one line, for example, or the output of the command to have special characters interpreted (think of security issues, for example). Edited to add "usually", though.